# I am using the package react-native-community/blur. But running the app throughs an error related to UIManager

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I have added the package: `react-native-community/blur` in my app. And tried running it. But it throws an error while running as mentioned below. Any fix to it or any solution??

```
Error:"Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "BlurView" was not found in the UIManager".
```

I have tried re-installing pods, also have checked with my yarn versions.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, Image, Text, findNodeHandle, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import { BlurView } from "@react-native-community/blur";

export default class Menu extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { viewRef: null };
  }

  imageLoaded() {
    this.setState({ viewRef: findNodeHandle(this.backgroundImage) });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Hi, I am some unblurred text</Text>
        <BlurView
          style={styles.absolute}
          viewRef={this.state.viewRef}
          blurType="light"
          blurAmount={10}
        />
        <Image
          ref={img => {
            this.backgroundImage = img;
          }}
          //source={{ uri }}
          source={{uri: 'https://facebook.github.io/react-native/img/tiny_logo.png'}}
          style={styles.absolute}
          onLoadEnd={this.imageLoaded.bind(this)}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center"
  },
  absolute: {
    position: "absolute",
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    right: 0
  }
});
```

Comment: Did you try this? `npm install --save @react-native-community/blur` and `react-native link @react-native-community/blur`

Comment: Oh Yes I did that at the very beginning, while adding the package to my App.

Comment: Does anyone know a fix to this??

Comment: Error occur due to Package is not being installed properly. Check Xcode -> Project Navigator -> Pods -> Products or Development Pods -> React-native-blur; it should be there. If the package is not there, then it is not installed.

Answer (score 1):

First, close your app.

if you are on android, open the android directory of your project in Android Studio and then sync your project with Gradle ( it may happen automatically but if it doesn't then do so yourself).

if ios, run `npx pod-install` or cd into the ios folder and run `pod install`.

Re-run your app. if android then run `npx react-native run-android`. if ios, run `npx react-native run-ios`

Answer (score 1):

flow this instruction:

1. Close your app
2. run it again with command: react-native run-ios

Note: Do not use npx or any other command, just run react-native run-ios

Answer (score 0):

in react native 60 >= on functional component

```
npm install --save @react-native-community/blur
```

then

```
react-native unlink @react-native-community/blur
```